# SwiftUI ColorPicker "opened" and "closed" events?

Tags: colors, swiftui, picker, color-picker

I need to be able to undo / redo the colors that are picked with the new SwiftUI ColorPicker ( on the iPad : it's presented as a floating window )

The thing that makes it very difficult is that there is apparently no way to know that ***the user has indeed chosen a color ( and therefore closed the panel )***

Instead, the behavior of ColorPicker is that it will keep updating the binded color as the user is manipulating the color controls. This is very helpful to show a live preview, but you don't want to register all these color variations for undo / redo purposes : you only want the color that was finally picked.

Therefore there is no logical distinction between the colors that the user ***tried***, and the one that was ***selected***

And I looked everywhere : there aren't any modifiers / notifications related to that.

I know SwiftUI hasn't been there for long, but this seems like a crucial functionality that's missing?

***Has anyone found a workaround?***

Comment: Not just a SwiftUI issue.

Comment: I have an idea for you, maybe you can think about making a custom palette which solve your issue.

Comment: @swiftPunk You mean, reinvent the ( color ) wheel? That would be the very last resort, and not really a *workaround*, as I was asking.

Comment: @matt Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean the flaw runs deep. For UIColorWell, as I say in my book, there is no way to learn when the view controller is dismissed or how it was dismissed. Makes it sort of useless, for various reasons, including the one you give. It's just shoddy design.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your answer. I tried wrapping UIColorWell with a coordinator and use the updateUIView function as a makeshift for "the state has changed", but it would trigger also when other parts of the UI change, making it useless for my purpose. That's indeed a bad design from Apple.

Comment: I wrapped UIColorPickerViewController in a UIViewRepresentable and tried messing with UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate's`continuously` flag but that doesn't really help. It lets you know that the user is continuously making a selection, but no signal when they are done. I was hoping it would call the delegate one last time with continuously = false.

Comment: I have the same issue. Anyone know a good SwiftUI color picker library? The built in picker seems almost useless for this reason...

Comment: @YarivAdam i have found one pretty interesting : Alderis on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

Undo is always tricky. One size does not fit all. In this case a good solution is to throttle the number of events that come into the `UndoManager`. You can do so by comparing the current time to the time you last commit.

Create a view model that represents your Source of Truth, and conform to `ObservableObject` to publish events. It will own the UndoManager. It will have a computed property that gets/sets to the internal data, and check the current time against the time of last commit.

```
class EditViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var commitTime = Date.now

    let undoManager = UndoManager()

    private var _color: Color = .red {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    var color: Color {
        get { _color }
        set {
            let oldValue = color
            let now = Date.now
            if now.timeIntervalSince(commitTime) > 1 {
                undoManager.registerUndo(withTarget: self) {
                    $0.color = oldValue
                }
            }
            self.commitTime = now
            _color = newValue
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now all that's left to do is create your view and pass in the binding. The implementation details are opaque to the View since it is managed by the ViewModel.

```
struct EditView: View {

    @StateObject var vm = EditViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ColorPicker("Color", selection: $vm.color)
        }
    }

}
```

If you need even more control, you can additionally compare the last committed color to the new value and only commit if there is a significant change.

I will also agree that a data-driven approach like SwiftUI's can make undo more tricky. For example, when you need to coalesce multiple operations together into one undo group. By its very nature an undo group is procedural-- the user did one thing after the other, and finally terminates on some condition. But I'm sure there is some way to encapsulate this step-wise operation in a transaction object of some kind.

Undo is hard!

Comment: I ended up implementing something similar : a time based check, but your implementation is neat! Thanks for the explanation too!